IoT leaf device receives RefusedNotAuthorized when using a transparent edge gateway to IoT Central
I am trying to send a message from a leaf device via a transparent gateway to IoT Central and getting RefusedNotAuthorized exceptions.
Both the gateway and the device were provisioned using the same device connection group.
All certificates were generated using https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/main/tools/CACertificates with the same root CA and intermediate CA certificates.
I am using this as the leaf device https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/main/samples/dotnet/EdgeX509AuthDownstreamDevice.
with the variables
export IOTHUB_HOSTNAME="iotc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net"
export IOTEDGE_GATEWAY_HOSTNAME="arkham.localdomain"
export DEVICE_ID="leaf-device-cert"
export DEVICE_IDENTITY_X509_CERTIFICATE_PEM_PATH="/certs/iot-edge-device-identity-leaf-device-cert-full-chain.cert.pem"
export DEVICE_IDENTITY_X509_CERTIFICATE_KEY_PEM_PATH="/private/iot-edge-device-identity-leaf-device-cert.key.pem"
export IOTEDGE_TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE_PEM_PATH="/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"
export MESSAGE_COUNT="2"
export DEVICE_CLIENT_PROTOCOL="Mqtt"

Edge Gateway configuration is
hostname = "arkham.localdomain"
trust_bundle_cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"

auto_reprovisioning_mode = "AlwaysOnStartup"
[provisioning]
source = "dps"
global_endpoint = "<https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/>"
id_scope = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

[provisioning.attestation]
method = "x509"
registration_id = "edge-gateway-device-cert"

identity_cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-identity-edge-gateway-device-cert-full-chain.cert.pem"
identity_pk = "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-identity-edge-gateway-device-cert.key.pem"

[agent]
name = "edgeAgent"
type = "docker"
imagePullPolicy = "on-create" # "on-create" or "never". Defaults to "on-create"

[agent.config]
image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.5"

[edge_ca]
cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-edge-gateway-device-ca-full-chain.cert.pem"
pk = "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-ca-edge-gateway-device-ca.key.pem"

In the deployment manifest of the gateway I have tried these environment variables set for edgeHub with the leaf device not attached to the gateway

"edgeHub": {
    "env": {
        "NestedEdgeEnabled": {
            "value": "false"
        },
        "AuthenticationMode": {
            "value": "CloudAndScope"
        }
    }

and these environment variables set for edgeHub with the leaf device attached to the gateway
"edgeHub": {
    "env": {
        "NestedEdgeEnabled": {
            "value": "true"
        },
        "AuthenticationMode": {
            "value": "Scope"
        }
    }

The Result is
Sending message: 0, Data: [{MyFirstDownstreamDevice "messageId":0,"temperature":21,"humidity":67}]CONNECT failed: RefusedNotAuthorized

and edgeHub logs are
[INF] [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.DeviceScopeAuthenticator] - Client leaf-device-cert in device scope not authenticated locally.

[DBG] [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Authenticator] - leaf-device-cert authentication failure

[ERR] [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceIdentityProvider] - Unable to generate identity for clientId leaf-device-cert and username arkham.localdomain/leaf-device-cert/?api-version=2020-09-30&DeviceClientType=.NET%2F1.42.3%2B2a97dd06e82cb67c5be8a7c7d189bef8048a3a86%20%28.NET%208.0.10%3B%20Ubuntu%2024.04.1%20LTS%3B%20X64%29

[INF] [EdgeHub] - "ClientNotAuthenticated, Client ID: leaf-device-cert; Username: arkham.localdomain/leaf-device-cert/?api-version=2020-09-30&DeviceClientType=.NET%2F1.42.3%2B2a97dd06e82cb67c5be8a7c7d189bef8048a3a86%20%28.NET%208.0.10%3B%20Ubuntu%2024.04.1%20LTS%3B%20X64%29, 22250e14"


How did you generate certificate

All certificates were generated using https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/main/tools/CACertificates
./certGen.sh create_root_and_intermediate ./certGen.sh create_edge_device_ca_certificate "edge-gateway-device-ca" ./certGen.sh create_edge_device_identity_certificate "edge-gateway-device-cert" ./certGen.sh create_edge_device_identity_certificate "leaf-device-cert"

The RefusedNotAuthorized exception occurs because the config.yaml file requires parameters for Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service.
Below is the IoT Edge configuration set in the config.yaml and the deployment manifest for edgeHub. I referred to this documentation to connect devices with X.509 certificates using Azure IoT Central.
hostname: "arkham.localdomain"
trust_bundle_cert: "file:///var/aziot/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"
auto_reprovisioning_mode: "AlwaysOnStartup"

provisioning:
  source: "dps"
  global_endpoint: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/"
  id_scope: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  attestation:
    method: "x509"
    registration_id: "edge-gateway-device-cert"
    identity_cert: "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-identity-edge-gateway-device-cert-full-chain.cert.pem"
    identity_pk: "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-identity-edge-gateway-device-cert.key.pem"

edge_ca:
  cert: "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-edge-gateway-device-ca-full-chain.cert.pem"
  pk: "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-ca-edge-gateway-device-ca.key.pem"


To create an Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service, register individual enrollments with X.509 certificates. I referred to this documentation for provisioning X.509 devices to Azure IoT Hub using a DPS enrollment group.

I also referred to this link to connect an IoT Edge transparent gateway to an application, and this documentation for creating IoT Edge devices at scale using X.509 certificates on Linux.



My config.toml has that attestation under [provisioning.attestation]. My problem is not with the provisioning of the gateway or the leaf device but in sending messages from the leaf device to IoT Central using a transparent gateway with x.509 certificates.

I tried Used certificate  to genreate leaf device and try to send message  using this doc . I trying with c# code as well.
